# spark structured streaming joining aggregate dataframe to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming dataframe that could look at some point like:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               owner|              fruits|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|Brian                | apple|
Brian                | pear |
Brian                | date|
Brian                | avocado|
Bob                | avocado|
Bob                | apple|
........
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I performed a groupBy, agg collect_list to clean things up.

```
val myFarmDF = farmDF.withWatermark("timeStamp", "1 seconds").groupBy("fruits").agg(collect_list(col("fruits")) as "fruitsA")
```

the output is a single row for each owner and an array of every fruit.
I would now like to join this cleaned up array to the original streaming dataframe dropping the fruits col and just having the fruitsA column

```
val joinedDF = farmDF.join(myFarmDF, "owner").drop("fruits")
```

this seems to work in my head, but spark doesn't seem to agree.

I get a

```
Failure when resolving conflicting references in Join:
'Join Inner
...
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Aggregate [name#17], [name#17, collect_list(fruits#61, 0, 0) AS fruitA#142]
```

When I turn everything into a static dataframe, it works just fine. Is this not possible in a streaming context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried renaming the column name? There is a similar problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19860

Comment: I actually figured that out, and forgot to update the thread.

Comment: @Brian does this code work for you? I'm using Kafka for both source and sink and, if using `outputMode("append")` I get `Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;` while if I use `outputMode("update")`, I get `Inner join between two streaming DataFrames/Datasets is not supported in Update output mode, only in Append output mode;;`.